# Which method (POST/GET) is using in the SoapClient to send HTTP requests?

Tags: php, soap, http-post, soap-client

I don't know if I'm asking a correct question! But I think its answer will guide me to solve my problem...

I'm trying to call a function by SoapClient,... It is a simplified version of my code:

```
class SOAP_AuthStruct {
    function __construct($user, $pass) {
        $this->Username = strval($user);
        $this->Password = strval($pass);
    }
}


$soap_loc = "SET TO SOAP PATH";

$soap_opts = array (
        'location'   =>  $soap_loc,
        'style'      =>  SOAP_DOCUMENT,
        'use'        =>  SOAP_LITERAL,
        'cache_wsdl' =>  WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions' =>  FALSE,
        'trace'      =>  TRUE
);


$testclient = new SoapClient("soapcall.wsdl", $soap_opts);

$soap_auth = new SOAP_AuthStruct("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
$soap_header = new SoapHeader($soap_ns,'AuthHeader',$soap_auth,FALSE);

// $a_param is filled with essential values
$soap_param = array("CreateTransaction" => $a_param);


try {
    $result = $testclient->__soapCall("CreateTransaction", $soap_param, NULL, $soap_header, $output_headers);

    echo $testclient->__getLastRequest();
    echo "\n\n";
    echo $testclient->__getLastResponse(); 
    echo "\n\n";
    echo $testclient->__getLastResponseHeaders(); 
    echo "\n\n";

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {

    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);

}
```

I have a sample of correct request format, and the getLastRequest() function shows that the request has the correct format...

but in response I have this Error Message:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
X-Mashery-Responder: XXXXX.mashery.com
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2011 18:34:29 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1293
```

I think (and I'm not sure about it!) that may be SoapClient use POST Method to send request, and I can't find it in the response header: "Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE"

Please let me know if you have any solution to my problem! and Also the answer to my question!

Many Thanks in advance for your help and your time ;)

**--------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE:**

OK, Now I know that it is sending POST Request!

I added this line to my code (after calling function)

```
echo $testclient->__getLastRequestHeaders();
```

and it returned:

```
POST /RimWebAPI/?api_key=APIKEY&sig=SIGNATURE   HTTP/1.1
Host: something.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.1.6
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "SOAP ACTION"
Content-Length: 2344
```

I'm still working on it, but I would appreciate any help or quide!

Comment: the response headers state that the method is not allowed, you need to send the data as a GET Request see: `Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE`

Comment: @RobertPitt: Thanks Robert, Now I'm sure about it! Do you know how I can change SoapClient Method to GET?!

Answer (score 1):

Is the Client HTTP POST calling the directory and not the script? I mean to say that it may be possible that /PATH_TO_API is a directory on the server and your script was index.php in that directory. In that case you will need to append a trailing slash to the POST command so that web-server would return the default document.
What do the server logs say when you get the 405 error? Further, can you send the parameter as a GET instead of POST.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited the PATH_TO_API to a similar format that I must call... The main path I'm calling is: something.com/RimWebAPI/?api_key=APIKEY&sig=SIGNATURE (And it seems that it is divided to Host and Path) And I don't have access to the server... unfortunately...